# How can i dynamicly change the font size and add a minimal font-size?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the `font-size` depending of the width of my browser window.

The font is resizing while i resize the browser window, but it doesn't prevent the `font-size` going under 18px.

```
  font_size();
  function font_size(ww,wh) {
    var title = document.getElementById("title").style.fontSize;
    if (title < 18) {
      $("#title").css("font-size", 18);
    }else{
      $("#title").css("font-size", ww*0.0315);
    }
  };
```

What's the issue with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Can we see your HTML?

The `.style` method on DOM elements would most likely give you the styles that has been added to that element using the `style` attribute and not any other internal or external CSS.

To fix that either use jQuery's `.css()` method or browser's inbuilt `getComputerStyle()` function.

Another point is that `.style()`, `.css()` and `getComputedStyle()` all returns strings and not numbers, so it is wise to parse the strings to numbers before using any comparison operators.

```
if ( parseInt(title) < 18) {
```

These two problems can be the cause. Sort it out and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript for this. CSS is up to the challenge.

```css
#title {
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media (min-width: 572px) {
  #title {
    font-size: 3.15vw;
  }
}
```

This sets `#title`'s `font-size` to 18px, unless the viewport is at least 572 pixels wide. At that size and wider, `#title`'s `font-size` is [3.15% of the viewport's width.](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) (My console tells me 3.15% of 572px is 18.018px, and it increases from there.)